# sql-to fetch reciprocal data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle db, which contains data like this, a+b, b+a, c+d, d+c.

My question is, when a+b = b+a, how to fetch distinct records.

```
PK         CODE
1000    87DIA4+BAJI204
1001    87DIA4+BIJI939
1002    87DIA4+C3IDI02
1003    87DIA4+C3IZI419
1004    BAJI204+87DIA4
1005    BIJI939+87DIA4
1006    C3IDI02+87DIA4
1007    C3IZI419+87DIA4
```

Comment: Unclear. Please add example data

Comment: Show us your data model and some sample data, please

Comment: A and B as string data type?

Comment: i understand what your saying but need to see an example of a table is it a row or a column. have you already tried anything? what variant of sql are you using?

Comment: Are a and b stored in two separate columns, or in the same column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle

Comment: When a+b and b+a are both present, which one should be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a sub-query which splits out the two elements from the `CODE` column. Then use a self-join to find the reciprocal pairs:

```
SQL> with cte as ( select pk
  2                       , substr(code, 1, instr(code, '+')-1) as str1
  3                       , substr(code, instr(code, '+')+1) as str2
  4                from your_table)
  5  select a.pk as a_pk
  6         , b.pk as b_pk
  7        , a.str1
  8        , a.str2
  9  from cte a
 10       join cte b
 11        on a.str1 = b.str2
 12           and a.str2 = b.str1
 13  where a.pk < b.pk
 14  order by a_pk;

      A_PK       B_PK STR1         STR2
---------- ---------- ------------ ------------
      1000       1004 87DIA4       BAJI204
      1001       1005 87DIA4       BIJI939
      1002       1006 87DIA4       C3IDI02
      1003       1007 87DIA4       C3IZI419

4 rows selected.

SQL>
```

The WHERE clause ensures the result set contains only one instance of each reciprocal pair.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you may need something like this:

```
with yourTable(PK, CODE) as (
    select '1000',    '87DIA4+BAJI204' from dual union all
    select '1001',    '87DIA4+BIJI939' from dual union all
    select '1002',    '87DIA4+C3IDI02' from dual union all
    select '1003',    '87DIA4+C3IZI419' from dual union all
    select '1004',    'BAJI204+87DIA4' from dual union all
    select '1005',    'BIJI939+87DIA4' from dual union all
    select '1006',    'C3IDI02+87DIA4' from dual union all
    select '1007',    'C3IZI419+87DIA4' from dual
)
select least( substr(code, 1, instr(code, '+') -1), substr(code, instr(code, '+') +1)) as A,
       greatest( substr(code, 1, instr(code, '+') -1), substr(code, instr(code, '+') +1)) as B
from yourTable
group by least( substr(code, 1, instr(code, '+') -1), substr(code, instr(code, '+') +1)),
       greatest( substr(code, 1, instr(code, '+') -1), substr(code, instr(code, '+') +1))
```

that gives:

```
A               B
--------------- ---------------
87DIA4          BAJI204
87DIA4          BIJI939
87DIA4          C3IDI02
87DIA4          C3IZI419
```

The idea is to separate the values in each row and, for each row, evaluate the "smallest" and the "greatest" value. This way, you can use these results  to group and get only one row A+B if you have A+B and B+A.

Answer (score 0):

As Aleksej and APC both pointed out, you need to split the `code` into components. And I am pleased to see they both offered the "right" solution (rather than the "lazy" solution) - to split `code`, use standard string functions `substr()` and `instr()`, not regular expressions.

The solution below also splits the `code`, in the same way. I use that for a `GROUP BY` clause, to group together the rows you consider "duplicates". Then from each group I just pick the one with the lowest `PK` value. **NOTE**: your problem statement is incomplete, you didn't state WHICH row should be kept from each pair. (Or, more generally, what to do with them... if the requirement is different, the solution below can be adapted.)

In each group I select `MIN(PK)` - that is self-explanatory. Then, to pick up the `CODE` value that belongs to that `PK`, I use the `FIRST` function; see the documentation if you are not familiar with it. (Some developers aren't.)

This solution reads the base data just once, and there are no joins.

```
with 
     test_data ( pk, code ) as (
                 select 1000, '87DIA4+BAJI204'  from dual
       union all select 1001, '87DIA4+BIJI939'  from dual
       union all select 1002, '87DIA4+C3IDI02'  from dual
       union all select 1003, '87DIA4+C3IZI419' from dual
       union all select 1004, 'BAJI204+87DIA4'  from dual
       union all select 1005, 'BIJI939+87DIA4'  from dual
       union all select 1006, 'C3IDI02+87DIA4'  from dual
       union all select 1007, 'C3IZI419+87DIA4' from dual
)
-- End of test data (not part of the solution!) SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select   min(pk) as pk, min(code) keep (dense_rank first order by pk) as code
from     test_data
group by    least(substr(code, 1, instr(code, '+')-1), substr(code, instr(code, '+')+1)),
         greatest(substr(code, 1, instr(code, '+')-1), substr(code, instr(code, '+')+1))
;

  PK   CODE          
----   ---------------
1000   87DIA4+BAJI204 
1001   87DIA4+BIJI939 
1002   87DIA4+C3IDI02 
1003   87DIA4+C3IZI419
```